# Android kills GL context when screen is locked

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have set `mView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);` and this works in most situations, but I recently noticed that if I lock the phone it kills the GL Context. The rest of the app seems to stay intact. I'm able to quit to the home screen and play another game, and go into the multitasker and still have my game waiting for me how I left it.

I have also found that if I go to the home screen and then lock the phone, the context is still intact. There is only a problem when I lock when inside the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have specific requirements for the lifetime of the EGL context, it's usually best to use a SurfaceView rather than a GLSurfaceView so that you have full control. It might be easier though to just let GLSurfaceView do what it wants, and repopulate the EGL context when the app resumes... that way you aren't holding on to resources while your app is idle.

Comment: I have it set up as a custom surface view. If I overload the context factory method destroyContext to do nothing it still removes the context when I lock the device.

Comment: SurfaceView has no context factory methods, which suggests that you're still working with GLSurfaceView. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for examples with SurfaceView and TextureView. Alternatively, debug the class itself -- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java -- and attempt to determine whether the fault lies with GLSurfaceView destroying contexts when it shouldn't, or something deeper in the system killing contexts when the device is locked.